# How to change a required field into optional/nullable in Entity Framework data migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There is some field that needs to be changed into nullable.

Originally,

```
public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

in FluentAPI,

```
Property(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Changed into

```
public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

in FluentApi,

```
Property(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .IsOptional()
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

But when I `Add-Migration` in the **Package Manager Console**, no change code is added:

```
public partial class EmployeeIdIsOptional : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Does it mean that EF cannot do this type of migration automatically?

A makeshift I can think of is to write Sql statement inside the `Up()` and `Down()` methods, like:

```
public partial class EmployeeIdIsOptional : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE Salaries ALTER COLUMN EmployeeId uniqueidentifier NULL");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE Salaries ALTER COLUMN EmployeeId uniqueidentifier");
    }
}
```

But is there a better way, a standard way to alter a column in data migration?

Comment: Generally making a property nullable creates a correct migration. Not sure how the use of the FluentAPI might affect things though.

Comment: But there got to be something in the `Up()` method to render the change in the database, isn't it?

Comment: Is this field a FK? Also you speak about `ExaminerId` field, but show confiruration of `EmployeeId`.

Comment: I've made the correction. `EmployeeId` is the FK.

Comment: Did you ever find the reason? I have the same today :/